# Stop event handler from running, after one click

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm writing some JavaScript code to execute tracking on hyperlinks.  Basically, if you click a link, it will fire off tracking to another system.

However, I only want tracking to be fired on the first click.
At the moment, my event handler fires on every click and I only want it to fire once.

With the code below, I'm using a `while loop`.  Which works for the first link, but it then means my event handler does not fire, when I click on other links...  So it stops running entirely.

Not sure of the best approach to handle this.

I'm grabbing a number from the value of aria-controls, on the link, using `event.target`.  Just to explain what I'm doing below:

```
   var apples         = object.apples; 
   var click          = 0;

    function sendTrackingData(event) {
        if (event.domEvent.target.hasAttribute("aria-controls")) {

            // Grab the value of aria-controls attibute
            var buttonAriaControlValue = event.domEvent.target.attributes["aria-controls"].value;


            //Only send report on the first click click
            while (buttonAriaControlValue && click < 2) {
                click++;

                //Take the last number of the value
                var number = buttonAriaControlValue.charAt(buttonAriaControlValue.length-1);

                var integer = parseInt(number);
                var final = integer + 1

                reportingService.sendReport({}, 'ClickReport', 'The value is: ' + final + ' of ' + apples);
        }
    }
}

fruitLinks.onDOMEvent('click', sendTrackingData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each link to be clickable once, you cannot use a global variable (click).

Here is a simple method, you just need to change the two commented lines

```
function sendTrackingData(event) {
    let target = event.domEvent.target;

    if ( target.attributes['stopTrack'] ) return;
    target.attributes['stopTrack'] = Date.now();

    //let trackValue = 343; // Take it from some target.attritues
    //let type = 'apple'; // Take it from some target.attritues
    reportingService.sendReport({}, 'ClickReport', 'The value is: ' + trackValue + ' of ' + type);
}

fruitLinks.onDOMEvent('click', sendTrackingData);
```

Comment: Hey @farvilain - thanks for this!  Wanted to understand why you were using Date.now?

And also, ['stopTrack'] - i guess you mean the aria-control attribute right?

Comment: stopTrack is just a name I choosed to know if the link must be tracked or not. Use what you want but be sure it's a dedicated attribute that will not be assigned to something else elsewhere in the code. Date.now is just something I do instead of true/false... replace it with 'true' if you want